# Two columns from one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a column in word which has two parts (one Persian and one English). I need to put tab space between the two languages (there is a single space between them). to clarify:

```
اجرای وصیت put in force a will; execution of a will  
اجرای وصیت نامه execution of will  
اجراییه ، قرار اجرای حکم دادگاه writ of execution
```

This is a part of the list, I need to add a tab between the Persian part and English part. So it becomes something like:

```
اجرای وصیت       put in force a will; execution of a will  
اجرای وصیت نامه      execution of will  
اجراییه ، قرار اجرای حکم دادگاه      writ of execution
```

is there anyway I can do this fast, either in word or excel?

Comment: (1) Is this question about Word or Excel? (What version?)  (2) You say “I need to put space between the two languages.”  Do you mean that *you already have* a space between the two languages?  (3) What is your question?      Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to unicode, so there might be a better way, but here goes. Copy the data from Word to Excel into column A. Use the following *array* formulas:

B1: `=TRIM(CONCAT(UNICHAR(IF(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>127,UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)),32))))`

C1: `=TRIM(CONCAT(UNICHAR(IF(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<=127,UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)),32))))`

The formulas are converting the string to numeric unicode characters, discarding the low or high values to return only one language or the other, then converting back to a string.

They need to be entered as *array* formulas, which means you have to use Ctrl-Enter instead of just Enter to enter the formulas. You'll see them displayed within curly braces {}.

Then, copy/paste columns B and C back to Word, pasting as Text-Only. You'll get tab separated columns in Word.

[image]

Comment: What is `CONCAT` any UDF,,? If it's `CONCATENATE` in that case the formula fails to split !!

Comment: @RajeshS CONCAT was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner,, thanks,, is  it similar to `CONCATENATE` ,, since i tried with `CONCATENATE` & it failed. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS no they are different CONCAT() will take a range, or array and combine them, while CONCATENATE() requires separate strings that it will then combine and will not take a range or array.

Comment: @RajeshS what this formula is doing is literally iterating the string character by character creating an array of characters based on their Unicode value.  This array is then passed to the CONCAT which combines them into one string, then removes errant spaces with TRIM.  CONCATENATE since it does not allow arrays, will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it did not work for me. I don't know why, even though I used array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

If one does not have CONCAT:

B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))>127),1)+1)
```

C1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")
```

The first finds the first English Character and splits on that.  Then the second removes what was found in the first from the original string:

[image]